# NSURLSessionTask authentication challenge completionHandler and NSURLAuthenticationChallenge client

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlprotocol, nsurlsessiondatatask

I am implementing a custom `NSURLProtocol`, and internally want to use `NSURLSession` with data tasks for internal networking instead of `NSURLConnection`.

I have hit an interesting problem and wonder about the internal implementation of the challenge handler of `NSURLSession`/`NSURLSessionTask`.

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task
                            didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge 
                              completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition, NSURLCredential *credential))completionHandler;
```

Here I am basically provided with two different challenge handlers, one being the `completionHandler` block, which is provided with all necessary information to handle the challenge, but there is also the legacy `NSURLAuthenticationChallenge.client` which has methods that correspond pretty much one to one with the `completionHandler` information options.

Since I am developing a protocol, and would like to pass certain authentication challenges upward the URL loading system for the calling API to implement, I need to use the `NSURLSession` client method:

```
- (void)URLProtocol:(NSURLProtocol *)protocol didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge;
```

My question is whether the internal implementation of the `completionHandler` and `NSURLAuthenticationChallenge.client` is the same, and if so, can I skip calling the completion handler in the delegate method, with expectance that the URL loading system will call the appropriate `NSURLAuthenticationChallenge.client` method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer my own question, the answer is no. Moreover, Apple's provided challenge sender does not implement the entire `NSURLAuthenticationChallengeSender` protocol, thus crashing when client attempts to respond to challenge:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFURLSessionConnection performDefaultHandlingForAuthenticationChallenge:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff06d958410'
```

My solution was to create a wrapper:

```
@interface CPURLSessionChallengeSender : NSObject <NSURLAuthenticationChallengeSender>

- (instancetype)initWithSessionCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition, NSURLCredential *credential))completionHandler;

@end

@implementation CPURLSessionChallengeSender
{
    void (^_sessionCompletionHandler)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition, NSURLCredential *credential);
}

- (instancetype)initWithSessionCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition, NSURLCredential *credential))completionHandler
{
    self = [super init];

    if(self)
    {
        _sessionCompletionHandler = [completionHandler copy];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)useCredential:(NSURLCredential *)credential forAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    _sessionCompletionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, credential);
}

- (void)continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    _sessionCompletionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, nil);
}

- (void)cancelAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge;
{
    _sessionCompletionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeCancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil);
}

- (void)performDefaultHandlingForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    _sessionCompletionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling, nil);
}

- (void)rejectProtectionSpaceAndContinueWithChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    _sessionCompletionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeRejectProtectionSpace, nil);
}

@end
```

And I replace the challenge object with a new one, using my wrapped sender:

```
NSURLAuthenticationChallenge* challengeWrapper = [[NSURLAuthenticationChallenge alloc] initWithAuthenticationChallenge:challenge sender:[[CPURLSessionChallengeSender alloc] initWithSessionCompletionHandler:completionHandler]];
[self.client URLProtocol:self didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:challengeWrapper];
```

Comment: Provided challenge sender?  You mean the NSURLProtocol base class?

Comment: Each challenge object has a sender property, however it is broken for protocols.

Comment: From a runtime perspective, there cannot realistically be any difference between passing the challengeWrapper object and implementing the exact same methods in your NSURLProtocol subclass and passing self as the challenge sender, which is what the docs say you should do.  I'm not sure why you have to implement those methods at all—that's probably a bug, and you should file one—but you should generally be passing your NSURLProtocol subclass as the sender, not a different object.

Comment: It is a bug, and I have filed it over a year ago. You are missing the problem. `NSURLAuthenticationChallenge` has a `sender`, which clients are supposed to call with actions on how to handle the challenge. However the object provided by Apple is partial and does not implement the entire `NSURLAuthenticationChallengeSender` protocol. So an app will crash on attempt to call methods. This wrapper implements these methods and calls the completion handler Apple provides that does work.

Comment: The crash is: `-[__NSCFURLLocalSessionConnection performDefaultHandlingForAuthenticationChallenge:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`. The Apple provided class `__NSCFURLLocalSessionConnection` does not implement the API correctly.

Comment: No, no, I'm not saying you shouldn't create a new challenge.  I'm saying you should create a new challenge, but pass your NSURLProtocol subclass instance as the challenge sender, not a different class.

Comment: From an aesthetic standpoint, I like the elegancy of a self-contained instance whose job is to just handle the auth-challenge.

Comment: Thanks a lot..  very helpful..  more so since neither Apple's docs or their sample code "CustomHTTPProtocol" are clear enough.

Comment: Thanks a ton, had the exact same problem today.